# Why is iwconfig in /sbin?

Tags: directory-structure

My Ubuntu boot has `iwconfig` living in `/sbin`.  I was under the impression that `/sbin` is usually for programs that are required for bootstrapping, or at least need to be available before `/usr` is mounted.

I don't really see how `iwconfig` fits either of these conventions, though.  What's the rationale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/), `/sbin` is a place where

> Utilities used for system administration (and other root-only commands) are stored.

And yes, `iwconfig` may be needed by some startup scripts before `/usr/` is mounted (if it uses a different partition) - therefore the place for it is not `/usr/sbin/`.

Comment: Why not `/usr/sbin`, then?  The FHS says it ["contains any non-essential binaries used exclusively by the system administrator."](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSBINNONESSENTIALSTANDARDSYSTEMBI)  I wouldn't exactly call wireless networks essential.

Comment: (See updated answer) Maybe *you* wouldn't, but some systems might need it, as it is related to network configuration.

Comment: Note that for some systems, wireless might be the only network connection.